# Javascript syntax: var array = [].push(foo);

Tags: javascript, arrays

Where **foo** is a defined variable, why is it that the following code:

```
var array = [].push(foo);
```

when outputted, equals **1**?
From my tests, outputting **array** will simply output the length of the array.
So the code:

```
var array = [10,20].push(foo);
```

would give a value of **3**.

As a related question (and to clarify what my code intended to do), why does this not intuitively do what it appears to do, ie:

```
var array = [];
array.push(foo);
```

where outputting **array** gives the expected result of **[foo]**?

Comment: If you have questions about the JavaScript standard API, I recommend to have a look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) first: *"**Returns** The new `length` property of the object upon which the method was called."*

Comment: @FelixKling right, thanks for the reference.  Probably should have done that earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use push method it returns length of array. So when you do:

```
var array = [10,20].push(foo);
```

you get [10, 20, foo] length of this array is three. But as you say var array it stores returned length from push method in this variable.

Answer (score 1):

Because the return value of push is the new length of the array [Documentation and examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

In your second example, you cited **outputting** the array, which is going to give you the new array in both cases. However, the returned result of your second case is the new array length as well

```
var array = [];
array.push(foo); //If you do this in the console, you'll see that 1 gets returned. 

console.log(array); //While this will print out the actual contents of array, ie. foo
```

Comment: Please don't reference [*w3schools*](http://www.w3fools.com), use the [*ECMAScript standard*](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-array.prototype.push) or [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) where examples may help.

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) always returns the new number of elements in the array. It does not return `this` instance or a new Array instance. `push()` is a mutator actually changes the contents of the array.

Answer (score 1):

instead you can try

```
  var array, foo = 30;
  (array = [10,20]).push(foo);
  console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 1):

`push` is a function and it returns an integer representing the length of the array.

Imagine the definition of this function as

```
int push(object obj);
```

When you do this:

```
var array = [].push(foo);
```

You are actually running the function and returning the value.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of `push()` method including two parts in javascript: Part 1: it adds one or more elements to the end of an array, part 2: it returns the new length of the array.

I think you are missing the part 2 in your understanding of this method.